# Magento 2 - show product attribute labels

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute

I'm able to display product attributes values as follow:

app/design/frontend/Vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
...

<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.formato" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.sku">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getManufacturer</argument>
    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">manufacturer</argument>
    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">manufacturer</argument>
    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">manufacturer</argument>
    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="manufacturer"</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>

...
```

The code above will print the value (e.g, **64**). How can I print the associated manufacturer's name (e.g, **Ferrari**)?

**edit**

My attribute.phtml is as follow:

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
    <div class="product attribute <?php echo $_className?>">
        <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php echo $_attributeLabel?>:</strong><?php endif; ?>
        <span class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php echo $_attributeValue; ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

eureka! Just add:

```
<argument name="at_type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
```

to the block's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

you have to edit/create your layout file:

```
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">               
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.manufacturer" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getManufacturer</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">manufacturer</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">manufacturer</argument>
                <argument name="at_type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>              
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Manufacturer</argument>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="manufacturer"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

this file must be edited:

```
/app/design/frontend/[TEMPLATE]/framework/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml


<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
 */
?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
<div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
    <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong>:<?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(is_array($_attributeValue)): ?>
        <div class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>>
        <?php echo implode(" - ", $_attributeValue)?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```